# HTTP status code for item being processed

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I have a single end point of a web service where you can queue items for processing by a bot. The items are queued, so it can take quite a while before they are actually processed.

If someone make a request, one of the following three options can occur:

1. The item is not yet in queue and will be queued. The end point will return *202 Accepted*.
2. The items has already been queued, but not yet processed. This is what I need a status code for.
3. The item has been processed and data is available. Either *200 OK* + data or *404 Not found* will be returned.

I have looked in [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) for ideas, but I don't really see anything for item's already in queue (step 2).

By name alone, the one called [208 Already reported](https://evertpot.com/http/208-already-reported) sounds good. But it appears to be specific to WebDAV, so that doesn't sound like a good idea to use.

Obviously [409 Conflict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409) sounds like a good option, but that would require another end point to handle returning the answer, once the item is processed. I might have trouble getting the people who designed the process to accept this.

What status code tells the client that their request is already being processed?

Comment: *"The representation sent with this response ought to describe the request's current status and point to (or embed) a status monitor that can provide the user with an estimate of when the request will be fulfilled."* Returning 202 Accepted with a Location that the client can poll for information is one way to do this, separate the "start process" endpoint from the "updates or outcome" endpoint.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that was also my initial argument, but I failed to convince the others working on the project. If it is the only reasonable solution, I will try again. I just wanted to seek out all options first.

Answer (score 0):

"HTTP Status 202 indicates that the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed"

[source](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-202-accepted/#:%7E:text=HTTP%20Status%20202%20indicates%20that,processing%20has%20not%20been%20completed.)